# Local file access in java script

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using Pannellum, a free panoramic viewer which uses HTML5, and developed using JavaScript.

http://www.mpetroff.net/archives/2012/05/28/introducing-pannellum/

The application works well, if the image is on web, but if it is local (assume that I have a html file locally and I want to open a panoramic file locally). It doesn’t work.

Is there any way that I can address a file locally and let this application works? It seems that it is using three.js and loads image using image() control.

I need to be able to use this application to download local file when it is opened in local browser. I am aware that a JavaScript from a web site cannot open a local file, bit in this case, al files are local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this wiki:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally